# Snowflake Data Load

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have received text file like below format

```
|1842035   |023851-005WA_ABCD|
|1842035   |023851-005WA_ABCD|
|1842035   |023851-005WA_ABCD|
|2270691   |023851-005WA_ABCD|
```

```
    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD
    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD
    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD
    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD
    994087  023851-005WA_ABCD
```

How do we load this to Snowflake ? It seems, these are the only format we can receive the files in text.

Comment: Your sample data appears to be in 2 different formats. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to clean in notepad++, because the data in one text file is 3 million +

Comment: Probably the only solution (if you don’t want to fix the file before you load it) is to load each record into a single column in a temp table and then fix it in Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

If the individual lines in the files are less than 16 Mb each, you can use the delimited (CSV) file format to read each whole line into a single column. From there you can transform the data using the following SQL:

```
with DATA as
(
select $1 as LINE from values
('|1842035   |023851-005WA_ABCD|'),
('|1842035   |023851-005WA_ABCD|'),
('|1842035   |023851-005WA_ABCD|'),
('|2270691   |023851-005WA_ABCD|'),
('    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD'),
('    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD'),
('    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD'),
('    973186  023851-005WA_ABCD'),
('    994087  023851-005WA_ABCD')
), CLEANED as
(
select regexp_replace(trim(replace(LINE, '|', ' ')), '\\s+', ' ') as A from DATA
)
select split_part(A,' ',1)::int as COL_1, split_part(A,' ',2) as COL_2 from CLEANED
;
```

| COL_1 | COL_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1842035 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 1842035 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 1842035 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 2270691 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 973186 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 973186 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 973186 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 973186 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |
| 994087 | 023851-005WA_ABCD |

Here is a file format that will read a whole line in a file as a single column. You may need to adjust it slightly for your files. It basically specifies that the row delimiter is a newline and there is no column delimiter:

```
ALTER FILE FORMAT "TEST"."PUBLIC".READ_LINES SET COMPRESSION = 'AUTO'
FIELD_DELIMITER = 'NONE' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 0
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'NONE' TRIM_SPACE = FALSE
ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE'
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT ='AUTO'
NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. \\s+ is used for ?

Comment: It replaces whitespace with a single space.